# I made a image look like a clickable button, but now when I click on it, does not act as hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my button code:

```
.info_button {
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-ms-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DkdX4Ci.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0  0;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #363024;
}
.info_button > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.info_button > header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.info_button > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.info_button > header  p a {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.info_button:hover{ 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
position:relative;
top:7px;
margin: 0;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="info_button" style="position:absolute; left:190px; top:25px;">
<header>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_self"><span id="info_button">              BoilerPlate of my Mansion</span></a></p>
</header>
</div>
```

This is fiddle for my work:
http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/ygosqouh/

The button functions exactly like I want it to be, but does not link to hyperlink when clicked. Please let me know if I am missing on something or need to add something.
Thanks.

Comment: Your CSS uses a class and your HTML uses an ID and a class of the same name. Maybe you should pick one.

Comment: I tried that already doesn't work.

Comment: In your fiddle your missing the anchor tag.

Comment: I'm not saying its causing the problem, it just looks like it could cause some confusion.

Comment: Is this want you want? http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1188/

Comment: @Donte'Trumble it has a anchor tag, isn't it <a></a> tag you are referring to.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble the fiddle you sent doesnt make the hyperlink work.

Comment: Try it now... It opens a new page to google.com http://jsfiddle.net/YhDXm/1189/. Forgot to add _blank.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble this works but i kinda defeats my work with the button styling, can you find something incorrect with my code.

Comment: Ok check this one http://jsfiddle.net/ygosqouh/3/

Comment: @Donte'Trumble this fiddle doesn't work for hyperlink, http://jsfiddle.net/ygosqouh/2/

Comment: yeah I made an update my fault http://jsfiddle.net/ygosqouh/3/

Comment: @Donte'Trumble it works for the text but is there a way to make whole image a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was you z-index on the anchor tag was set to 0; Once you change it to a positive z-index i.e 100 the link is now clickable.

```
.info_button > header p a {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

As for making the entire button clickable you would have to modify the HTML like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
   <div class="info_button" style="position:relative; left:190px; top:25px;">
        <header>
          <p><span id="info_button">
             BoilerPlate of my Mansion</span></p>
        </header>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
<a href="..."> <img src="..."> </a>
```

Comment: I cant use the img tag, i have to include the image in css

Comment: So why did you include the img tag in your fiddle? You are confusing me @starter

Comment: I am sorry, my fiddle got overwrtitten, this was my original fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/ygosqouh/

Answer (score 0):

So the Answer for my question came from @Donte'Trumble.
CSS code:

```
.info_button {
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-ms-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DkdX4Ci.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0  0;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #363024;
}
.info_button > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.info_button > header1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.info_button > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.info_button > header  p {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.info_button:hover{ 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
position:relative;
top:7px;
margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<div class="info_button" style="position:absolute; left:190px; top:25px;">
    <header><p><span id="info_button">BoilerPlate of my Mansion</span></p>
    </header>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/ygosqouh/
The problem was with my z-index, have to make it a positive interger, so changed it to 100 from 0, thanks again @Donte'Truble.